# How to change Select List values based on other Select List value using oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I have two select lists in my page, `Region` and `Country`.

`Country` should display values based on the value selected from the `Region` list. But the problem is, it's displaying blank in the `Country` list, even after selecting a value from the `Region` list.

```
 Region table                              Country table

 Id                                        Group_Id
 Name                                      Name
                                           Id
```

For `Region`, I have written the query as follows:

```
Select Name d,Id r from Regions
```

The query for Country as:

```
Select Name d,Id r from Country where Group_Id = :P3_REGION
```

[image]

How can I get the correct values?

Answer (score 2):

`P3_REGION` should be entered as **Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)** of the `Country` SelectList.